# php chart mysql row search by date

Tags: php, mysql, charts

this script working fine but how can i create search by date like i m searching 2012/1/1 to 2012/12/31

these are two scripts both works properly but i want to know that how i can join both together???because i want to create a chart which search date between to date

and this is chart script

```
include 'create.php';
$sql="SELECT due_date,total FROM $tablename"; // Give Your field Name  +
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$graphtitle='BarChart';//Graph Title
$xname='Chart For The Year Of 2012 '; //X-axis Name
$yname='Sale Chart';//y-axis name
$img_width=600;//image height
$img_height=300;//image width 
$margins=70;
$ymargin=6;
$count=mysql_affected_rows();
$graph_width=$img_width - $margins * 2;
$graph_height=$img_height - $margins * 2; 
$bar_width=25;
$total_bars=$count;
$gap= ($graph_width- $total_bars * $bar_width ) / ($total_bars +1);
$img=imagecreate($img_width,$img_height);
include 'barcolor.php';
imagefilledrectangle($img,0,0,0,0,$bag_color);
imageline($img,$margins,$img_height-45,$img_width-20,$img_height-45,$xyline_color);
imageline($img,$margins,$ymargin,$margins,$img_height-45,$xyline_color);
$maxvalue="select max(total) as total from $tablename";//Give your field name for Y axis 

$max=mysql_query($maxvalue);
while($inf1= mysql_fetch_array($max)) 
  {
   $ratio=$graph_height/$inf1[0];
  }
$horizontal_lines=8;
$horizontal_gap=($img_height+20)/$horizontal_lines;
for($j=1;$j<=$horizontal_lines;$j++)
{
        $y=($img_height-48) - $horizontal_gap * $j ;
        //imageline($img,$margins+1,$y,$img_width-20,$y,$hline_color);
        $v=intval($horizontal_gap * $j /$ratio);
        imagestring($img,2,$margins-30,$y-5,$v,$values_color);
}
$i=0;
while($inf = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  {
      $x1=($margins+10) + ($gap+5) + $i * ($gap+$bar_width) ;
      $x2=$x1+$bar_width;
      $y1=($img_height-46)- ceil($inf[1] * $ratio) ; 
      $y2=($img_height-46); 
      imagestring($img,2,$x1+1,$y1-15,$inf[1],$values_color); 
      imagestring($img,2,$x2-23,$img_height-43,$inf[0],$values_color);  
      imagefilledrectangle($img,$x1,$y1,$x2,$y2,$bar_color); // Draw bar
   $i++;   
  }
imagestring($img,8, ($img_width-$margin)/2, 0, $graphtitle, $txt_color);
imagestring($img,5, ($img_width-$margin)/2, $img_height-($ymargin+10), $xname, $txt_color);
imagestringup($img,5,10,($img_height-$ymargin)/2, $yname, $txt_color);
//header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($img, 'barchart.jpg');
echo "<div style='border:1px solid #d8d8d8;width:$img_width'><img src='barchart.jpg'></div>";
?>
```

and this is 2nd script which show 2 row sum show by between 2 date but i dont want a sum i want only chart which create by betwen to date

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tcal.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="tcal2.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
<form action="index2.php" method="post">
From: <input name="from" type="text" class="tcal"/>
To: <input name="to" type="text" class="tcal"/>
<input name="" type="submit" value="Seach" />
</form><br />
Total Sales:  
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","db_search","password12");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("db_search", $con);
function formatMoney($number, $fractional=false) {
    if ($fractional) {
        $number = sprintf('%.2f', $number);
    }
    while (true) {
        $replaced = preg_replace('/(-?\d+)(\d\d\d)/', '$1,$2', $number);
        if ($replaced != $number) {
            $number = $replaced;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $number;
}       
$a=$_POST['from'];
$b=$_POST['to'];
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT sum(salary) FROM accounts where date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
        $rrr=$row['sum(salary)'];
        echo formatMoney($rrr, true);
    }
mysql_close($con);
?>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you copy the sql query from the 2nd script to your first script? When you add the between clause script to the first clause it solves your problem?

Comment: yes i already try to copy sql query and put it in 1st script but script  is not working :(

Comment: I think you need to ask another question. You need to post your mysql database structure and try to code yourself. Then return here. It's too much code and we aren't here to make your homework.